# Server takes the post but android app pauses before take the response. How to handle?

Tags: android

Hello and sorry for my bad english,

I develop an android app and i face a bug.

There is an app and a server. The server creates some coupon ids and sends them over gcm to the app.

The app saves them in sqlite. When i select one coupon id and i press a button it is using an AsyncTask to connect to server and posting the coupon id. The server looks at the database to see if he can find the id and if yes, he deletes it and responses back success = 1. If the server does not find the id, this means that this id is used (and deleted) before and responses success = 0. In that way you can only use each coupon one time.
  Now the app, if takes back response = 1 shows a message that the coupon is ok and deletes it from sqlite (it' s important to show the message). The problem occurs in this situation:

When onpause() is called i choose to cancel the task to prevent other problems. Most times works well. But there is a bug if events occur with that timing:

The app tells server to check for coupon.
Server finds and deletes it and the same time the app is paused so the task is canceled (or the internet connection goes down).
The app takes no response and shows no message and does not delete from sqlite. 
Now the app still has in sqlite the coupon and "thinks" that it is not used yet.
The next time that the app asks the server for the same coupon id, the server does not find it and responses success = 0.

I don't know how to handle it.

thank you in advance

edited: Generally seems good advice to mark them rather than deleting but still have some problems. The story goes like this: The owner of a shop writes an offer of a product makes 10 coupons to the server (without knowing about coupons). Then the server sends them to 10 random users of the app. The user goes to the owner and shows the details of the app with the offer (nobody knows about coupons), then presses the button and server responds: "ok. the coupon is ok (you are not a hacker). You can have the product". Then the app deletes the coupon from sqlite. If the user roots the phone and restores the sqlite, trying to hack my app, he will have the same offer but my server will tell him that it is not a valid coupon.

Comment: First of all, requests/tasks must not be tied to activities or other stuff that can be easily destroyed

Comment: Should i use a retain fragment or you suggest something else? The problem is that i want to tell user what server responses.If activity is destroyed there is no meaning to continue the task

Comment: I suggest using service to which an activity can be bounded. So if activity is paused service is not destroyed, and then activity is unpaused, you can connect it to service again and see results of task.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will keep it in mind but maybe for other situations. In this situation i want to get the answer while the user is on the shop. I don't want him to leave and after that to take the answer because the owner of the shop must see the whole process... If the process is canceled i want the server to cancel it too.But this is impossible in some situations since the process maybe is cancelled because of internet connection problem so i can' t tell server t not to delete the coupon.That's why i try to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

That's a design problem. You should not delete your entries, only mark them so. However, if you really need to delete them, from 2 places, then you have to somehow synchronize them. Possible solution is storing information about outgoing request in SharedPreferences, and clearing them only when execution continued normally. Pseudo code:

```
onPreExecute {
    saveValues(vals);
}
doInBackground {
    doRequest();
    resp = new CustomResponseObj();
    if(requestCode==200){
        resp.success = true;
        resp.couponVal = ???;
    } else {
        resp.success = false;
    }
    return resp;
}
onPostExecute {
    if(resp.success){
        removeFromDb();
    } else {
        rememberToCheckAgainWithServer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice advice to mark them but still have some problems. I updated the question if you can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is with the approach of different response types?
i.e implement 3 different response types: deleted, error, not_found

I am sorry for my english.
Steve

edit: thanks for the hint, deleted first answer

Comment: "If the entry could not be found on the server, delete it on the device as well." - That changes the meaning in situation as described in question, i.e. when request is made, but response is not received.

Answer (score 0):

As Semyon Danilov said in comment. Make atomic operation of it (request and deleting the local record). Move it to separate service and use broadcast or binding to tell the app to show the info or add Notification, that launches the app and shows the info again.